# Curl + IMAP Doesn't save email body to file

Tags: curl, ssh, imap

I have a problem and I can't solve it! The problem is the following, I connect to the IMAP account in the terminal using Curl to receive a letter by UID in the terminal, the response comes with the letter that I request, but when I try to save the result to text, it saves one line with the size of the letter to the file and that's it. There is no letter! How to solve this problem please tell me.

Thanks to all!

`curl -v -u '*****:*****' imap://mail.mydomen.com/INBOX -X 'UID FETCH 1 BODY[]'`

string to file: * 1 FETCH (UID 1 BODY[] {2940}

I need to save the body of the letter with headers to a file, but saves only one line.

Comment: That line means "message 1 has UID 1 and the entire body is the following 2940 bytes", so I assume the entire response is actually received, but something assumes that IMAP responses are just one line, and elides all the other lines.